# How to express either forward or backward ranges in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift4

Is there a clean way to express both a forward and backward iterable range in Swift?

```
let range = forward ? (x+1)..<count : (0..<x).reversed()

for i in range {
  // ...
}
```

This does not work because CountableRange and ReversedRandomAccessCollection<(CountableRange)> are not compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a type eraser. The standard library provides [`AnyCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anycollection), which does just the trick:

```
let range = forward ? AnyCollection((x+1)..<count) : AnyCollection((0..<x).reversed())

for i in range {
  // ...
}
```